# How do I run a shell script and insert the output back into Android Studio?

Tags: android, scripting

In Android development, I need to create a lot of constant strings. There doesn't seem to be a quick way to do this in Android Studio, so I wrote a script to generate some code. This works on a Mac:

```
#!/bin/bash
[[ -z $1 ]] && NAME=XXX || NAME=$(echo $1 | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]')
OUT="public final static String ${NAME} = \"$(uuidgen)\";"
echo "${OUT}" | tee >(pbcopy)
```

Feel free to take this if you like.

I'd like to be able to invoke this shell script and insert the output back into the source code easily. Assign a hotkey to it or select a menu item. Or put it into the Generate menu. How would I go about doing this?

Or perhaps there's already a built-in way to do this and I don't know about it?

Answer (score 0):

Well. That was a round-about solution.

Basically, use Automator to create a service and assign a keyboard shortcut to it. Make sure to add Android Studio as an app that can control your computer.

[image]